Custom Computed Field is not getting indexed
I am trying to create a Computed Field (_pdfcontent) to store the content of PDF documents.
I have written a class that extends IComputedIndexField to create the computed field.
public class ComputedIndexPdfContent : IComputedIndexField
{
    private static readonly ILog CustomLog = LogManager.GetLogger(LogConstants.LoggerName);
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        try
        {
            var sitecoreIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

            if (sitecoreIndexable == null) return null;

            var pdfContent = new SitecorePdfParser(new MediaItem(sitecoreIndexable)).ExtractText().ToList();

            if (pdfContent.Count == 0) return null;

            return string.Join(" ", pdfContent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CustomLog.Error("Unable to assemble PDF content for the search index "+e);

            Log.Error("Unable to assemble PDF content for the search index ", e, this);
            return null;
        }
    }

}

The implementation of SitecorePdfParser and ExtractText in above code is as below.
public SitecorePdfParser(MediaItem item)
 {
     if (item.MimeType != "application/pdf")
         return;
     using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         Stream s = item.GetMediaStream();
         if (s != null)
         {
             //Converting stream to Memory Stream
             s.CopyTo(ms);
             //using iTextSharp dll to handle iref streams feature introduced with Acrobat 6
             _doc = CompatiblePdfReader.Open(ms);
             //_doc = PdfReader.Open(s);  --Old Code
         }
     }
 }
public IEnumerable<string> ExtractText()
{
    if (_doc == null)
        yield break;
    foreach (PdfPage page in _doc.Pages)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < page.Contents.Elements.Count; index++)
        {

            PdfDictionary.PdfStream stream = page.Contents.Elements.GetDictionary(index).Stream;
            foreach (string text in ExtractTextFromPdfBytes(stream.Value))
            {
                yield return text;
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried to debug the code. SitecorePdfParser always returns the null values.
Then I checked the Index configurations and I noticed that crawler added in the index is pointing to Home Item in the content.
Code is expecting the MediaItem
I added another crawler to the configuration which will crawl through the Media Library folder.
<crawler name="PDFItems" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>Media Folder Path</Root>
          </crawler>

This solution worked after rebuilding the index. I can see that _pdfcontent is getting indexed with the content of PDF files.
